# Will the first string in a tuple returned by re.findall() always be the longest matching string?

Tags: python, regex

```
re.findall(r'((([0-9]|[a-z]|[A-Z]){5,8}, )*([0-9]|[a-z]|[A-Z]){5,8} reporting and syncing)', 'johnny, joda89 reporting and syncing heyff, jkojo, jkjkjdf, 2378a reporting and syncing and a lot of other jazz. I looked into whether 34987, 22187, and 36547 will report, but no one has gotten back with me about that. Also 34298 reporting and syncing.')
```

gives me

```
[('johnny, joda89 reporting and syncing', 'johnny, ', 'y', '9'), ('heyff, jkojo, jkjkjdf, 2378a reporting and syncing', 'jkjkjdf, ', 'f', 'a'), ('34298 reporting and syncing', '', '', '8')]
```

In this example, the first string of each tuple is the longest. Will that always be the case? If someone knows where the other strings in each tuple are coming from, I would love to know that too! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Will that always be the case?

No, that is never the case. Matches are returned from *left to right*.

[`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall)

> The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the
>   order found

Comment: I see that each tuple is a match and the order of those tuples in the list follows along with the order of the matches from left to right in the string. I don't understand why the second, third and fourth strings in each tuple are there and am trying to figure out if the longest match will always be the first string in each tuple, as they are in the example above.

Comment: Does anyone know why the second, third, and fourth strings of each tuple are returned in the example above, or how I can modify the regex so that they are not returned?

Comment: `findall` returns either full matches if there are no captures, or tuples of captured groups. A capture is any pair of plain parentheses `(...)`, and they are encountered in order. For example, you last capture is `([0-9]|[a-z]|[A-Z])`, which only matches one character; so every last tuple member is a single matched character. To avoid that, you can convert them to non-capturing groups: `(?:...)` (just insert `?:` as the first thing inside the parentheses).